# How to call functions in Handler Monad from IO Monad

Tags: haskell, yesod

I am building a web application in Yesod .

I have two function of type

```
funA :: String -> IO ()
funB :: String -> Handler (Either a b)
```

Is there any way I can call funB from inside funA ,something of this sort

```
  res <- funB
   case res of ...
```

without changing the type of funA .

I am not very clear on what the run function of a monad does, but I have used it in some other libraries to this effect , but for Yesod the runHandler method is for internal use only.Does it have some other method for the same task?

Comment: Yes, you can use `liftIO`, so `res <- liftIO funB`.

Comment: Ahh sorry, read it the opposite way, you can use `handler`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the `yesod-simple` (or friends) template of stack, then by default, the template will contain a function named [`handler` [GitHub]](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack-templates/blob/c9d9d5699f3bfd58fef0a279afe23bf3b77ea749/yesod-simple.hsfiles#L606):

> ```
> -- | Run a handler
> handler :: Handler a -> IO a
> handler h = getAppSettings >>= makeFoundation >>= flip unsafeHandler h
> ```

This thus enables you to run a `Handler a` in an `IO a`.

You can thus run your function like:

```
funA :: String -> IO ()
funA parameter = do
    res <- handler (funB parameter)
    case res of
        Left x -> ...
        Right y -> ...
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need ,but I get the variable not in scope handler:: Yesod.Core.Types.HandlerFor Foundation.App (Either String String) -> IO (Either String b0) , is there something I need to import ? I used the yesod scaffolded yesod-postgress template to start building the server

Comment: @TanmayBhattacharya: it is defined in the `Application` module, so you might need to import it in `import Application(handler)`.